# Play audio files with default player

Tags: android, controls, android-mediaplayer, media

I want to play an MP3 file using the default Android player. I managed to get the file playing but it plays in the background. I want to have all the nice controls for pausing, playing, etc.

My code now is something like:

```
String link = "http://www.example.com/file.mp3";

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(link);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

How can I do it that when this file begins to play to go to another screen with the player and all the nice controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MediaPlayer` class should be used when you want to implement your own media player. If you want to use an existing player, you'll have to launch the appropriate intent, for example:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.site.com/file.mp3");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

If the particular Action doesn't work, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Hello! Thanks very much. This works but it is not actually what I want. I would like the file to open in the default android player. I see my mistake with the MediaPlayer class but using the method you described does not give me much control of what happens after the intent is lunched. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: For example I want to be able to navigate back after the intent lunched without the song being stopped

Comment: That's largely up the the particular music player. Most players launch a service in the background, which keeps playing the music, but as far as I know there is no public interface for accessing those services. You can take a look here http://www.alexc.me/android-music-app-service-currently-playing-song/231/, but this uses a undocumented interface, and most likely only works for devices running a vanilla Android version.